# unable to run Cobol-DB2 batch program

Tags: db2, cobol

My Cobol-DB2 batch program does not get invoked. A display that is the very first statement in the program does not show up in sysout. I've used the correct plan name and pointing to the DB2 sub-system associated with the plan.
Program execution JCL end with RC=12 and shows message DSNE100I DB2-sub-system-name NOT OPERATIONAL, RETRY COUNT IS ZERO.
Other than this there is not other display in sysout.
From the same DB2 sub-system, through SPUFI I, able to execute queries.
If any one can point to any possible issues, it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your batch job is running on a different LPAR than your TSO session.

If the DB2 subsystem is active on LPAR A and your TSO session is running on LPAR A then your SPUFI will work as expected, but if your batch job runs on LPAR B then it will not be able to find the DB2 subsystem.

Your IT shop may have a mechanism to force a batch job to run on a particular LPAR, maybe via a job class.  Or maybe your IT shop has a product such as ThruPut Manager to force a batch job to run on an LPAR where a specified resource is available.

Or, maybe you have specified an incorrect name for the DB2 subsystem in your DSN SYSTEM command.

Comment: DB2 subsystem name in DSN SYSTEM command is not incorrect. I'll check regarding the job class I'm using.